# Using a string function to display specific data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a string function that will display data from my table where 2 values end in 1.

For example

```
int_id     int2_id
101        302
201        301
```

Here the data I would want to show is the 201/301 due to the fact that they both end in 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `int_id` LIKE '%1' and `int2_id` LIKE '%1';
```

The `%` character is a wildcard character that matches anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use [modular arithmetic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE int_id % 10 = 1 AND int2_id % 10 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE RIGHT(int_id, 1) = 1 AND RIGHT(int2_id, 1) = 1
```